# Error, text to long when written to file?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to plot 2 graphs or more in one graph in gnuplot, but when I try to compile this

```
write(write_unit,*)'plot ''solchange.txt'' using 1:2 title ''Solchange'' with lines, ''solchange1.txt'' using 1:2 title ''Solchange1'' with lines'
```

I get the error: [image]

What is going wrong here? The funny thing is that it works with the following code:

```
write(write_unit,*)'plot ''solchange.txt'' using 1:2 title ''S'' with lines, ''solchange1.txt'' using 1:2 title ''S1'' with lines'
```

My text is shorter with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the output to the text file that's too long, it's the line of source code.  It is longer than 132 characters, so split the line into two using a continuation line.

Comment: How do I use a continuation line?

Comment: You use an `&` at the end of the line to be continued.  You will find more info with a web search, e.g., "fortran 95 continuation line"